# Creating a local HTTP listener in Delphi

Tags: delphi, listener, httpserver, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a windows desktop app written in Delphi 11 that I am integrating with Xero accounting.
The first step is complete, which is using ShellExecute to open a browser with a generated url that gives the user the chance to login.
A parameter of the url used is a redirect uri which includes a port.

How can I create a local http listener in Delphi 11 that will receive the data sent back by Xero?

Comment: It seems you need a local HTTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new application, drop a TIdHTTPServer component on it (or create it in code), set its Active property to True, and implement its OnCommandGet method, for example like this:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  ShowMessage(ARequestInfo.URI);
end;
```

Comment: FYI, the `OnCommand...` events are fired in the context of worker threads, and `ShowMessage` is not thread-safe. Use the`AResponseInfo` object to send data back to the client

Comment: I have the TIdHttpServer working now and it's returning the info I need in the URL bar of the browser. How do I get what I need in the delphi app via the OnCommandGet event? The URL being returned is:
http://localhost:8080/callback?code=SOMrd6QIfjy76J8JHt52Q-mpdr4fwO8rldUuPwCAlyC8&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20accounting.transactions&state=123456789&session_state=03rBrVvru1SYegdGU5OSaw4CqCRV61IHq7M8c4c5Jcs.Mc2E14MiI9P5ZJCMT13nwg
What I'm actually after is the Code and State parameters.

Comment: The Code and State parameters are part of the URI string, so you can pick them out from there using ordinary simple string manipulation, or using the convenient Params property, e.g. ARequestInfo.Params.Values['code']

Comment: Using Params.Values['code'] worked a treat. Cheers.